# Angular ng-model dynamic getters and setters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I want to use ng-model with an external model-service. This model has two methods: getValue(variable) and setValue(variable).

So in my html I want to be able to do:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="balance">
```

> Note: balance is not defined on $scope in my controller. And because we are dealing with more then 4000 different variables, I don't want to define them all on $scope.

And then on change it must call the setValue() method of the model. So in my controller I would like to have something like:

```
$catchAllGetter = function(variable) { // e.g. variable = 'balance'
     var value = Model.getValue(variable);
     return value;
}

$catchAllSetter = function(variable, value) { // called on change
     Model.setValue(variable, value);
}
```

Is something like this possible with Angular?

Comment: Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/BDyAs/12/

Comment: Don't think this helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach is similar to @Dan Prince, but the implementation differs a bit

Create a directive, that accepts name of the model variable, and then inject your model service in the directive itself to perform the getting and setting.

> Edit : As specified by @Werlang, writing an attribute that replaces
>   ngModel will refrain you from features like  validation, formatting,
>   debounced update, ng-change etc. So instead of writing a replacement,
>   we will instead wire up a supplementary attribute

.

```
    app.directive('dynamicInput', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {
              scope.variableName = angular.copy(attr.ngModel); // Saving the variable name

              scope[attr.ngModel] = (attr.ngModel + '_1'); // Setting a dummy value in the scope variable.
              // In your case it will look something like scope[attr.ngModel] = Model.getValue(attr.ngModel);

                scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {

                  console.log(scope.variableName + " ==> " + newValue);

                  //Model.setValue(scope.variableName, newValue);

              });

        }
      };
    })
```

Then in your HTML :

```
    <input ng-model='balance' dynamic-input />
```

Comment: This way you loose all functionality build-in to ng-model, like validation, formatting, debounced update, ng-change, etc

Comment: @TechMa9iac thanks for the edit, looks like a nice solution! I'll try it today.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new directive which implements this behaviour.

```
<input model-getter='getFn()' model-setter='setFn($value)' />
```

This would be fairly straightforward to implement:

```
app.directive('modelGetter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      get: '&modelGetter',
      set: '&modelSetter'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.val(scope.get());
      element.on('change', function() {
        var val = element.val();
        scope.set({ $value: val });
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: This way you loose all functionality build-in to ng-model, like validation, formatting, debounced update, ng-change, etc

Answer (score 1):

look at [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xQq3zjnlUNipVGEr1Uom?p=preview), i created for you. I hope I have understood you correctly

```
$scope.$watch('variables', function(newValue) {
  console.log("triggers on variables change");
  angular.forEach(newValue, function(value, key) {
    Model.setValue(key, value);
  });  
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngModel` supports getter and setters. Here's how it works:

```
<input ng-model="balance" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">
```

This works if `balance` is a getter/setter function:

```
$scope.balance(100);      // sets 100
var b = $scope.balance(); // returns 100
```

You don't need to expose each variable on the scope - you could just expose the `Model` service that you use in your example:

```
$scope.Model = Model;
```

then, in the View, bind to whatever property you need:

```
<input ng-model="Model.balance" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have all your variables in an object array:

```
[
  {key: "Variable 1", value: 1, kind: "number"},
  {key: "Variable 2", value: "some text", kind: "text"},
  {key: "Variable 3", value: new Date(), kind: "date"}
]
```

Then in your view you shall create them with the help of an ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="variable in myVariables">
    <input type="{{variable.kind}}" ng-model="variable.value" ng-change="changed(variable)">
</div>
```

If you need to update your external service, implement a method changed(variable) in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

ES5 Object properties to the rescue:

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'balance', {
  enumberable: true,
  get: function () {
    // -- call your getter here
  },
  set: function (val) {
    // -- call the setter here
  }
});
```

This is native Javascript, so it does not get faster than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate your model function dynamically, e.g.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel(var)">
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.myModel = function(var) {
  return function(newValue) {
     // this is a regular model function but you can use 'var' here
     ...
  }
}
```